# Application_Error event in Global.asax not firing in Release Mode? ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, global-asax, nlog, application-error

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application. I'm having a problem where my Application_Error() event in my Global.asax file isn't firing in Release Mode. If I compile in Debug it fires just
fine.

PS: I'm using NLogger to log my runtime errors.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it's just not NLogger that doesn't log in Release mode? How do you know `Application_Error` isn't firing?